# A simple area problem

Tags: geometry, area

I found this problem from a book (level = grade 7).

[image]

In the attached figure, ABCD is a square with sides 10 units. Need to find the area of the quadrilateral PQRS built inside it as shown. The only information given is XQ = 3 and YR = 4.

Of course, it can be solved by letting BX = a, DR = d and express other line segments in terms of these unknowns. The required area $= 10^2 – (\frac {1}{2}) [(a)(4 + d) + (6 – d)(a + 3) + … ] = 56$

In the process, the ‘a’ and the ‘d’ (and also the ‘ad’ term) miraculously disappeared.

My questions are:-

1) Besides the ‘3’, ‘4’, ‘10’ combination can do this trick, what else?

2) Can it be solved by some other simpler methods (like cutting it up differently so that lesser expansions of brackets are involved).

Comment: Can you clarify your first question? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @user37238 I mean: are they lucky numbers. If we replace 3 by some other numbers (like 5) and 4 by (say 4 + k for some number k), will the a and d disappear after the expansion and cancellation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the side be of length $S$ and the segments lengths on four sides be $a,b,c,d$. Then the double of the complement area ($2\cdot$ area of triangles) is
$$
A=a(S-b)+b(S-c)+c(S-d)+d(S-a)=S(a+b+c+d)-(a+c)(b+d).
$$
So as long as $S$, $a+c$ and $b+d$ are given constants, the area can be found.

**Addendum:** if we call $x=S-a-c$ ($=3$ above) and $y=S-b-d$ ($=4$ above) then $A=S^2-xy$ and the required area is
$$
S^2-\frac12 A=\frac12(S^2+xy).
$$
It shows that an alternative cut would be to draw lines through the vertices of the quadrilateral parallel to the sides and consider the rectangles in the middle (the central rectangle with the area $xy$ is overlapping).

Comment: Re-writing your last statement, I get $A = S^2 - \frac {xy}{2}$ (always). Does that mean "As long as x and y are both less than or equal to 10, the whole thing works". Right?

Comment: @Mick $A=S^2-xy$ (no one-half). Yes, the problem works for any $x,y\le 10$ (well, the side length $10$ can be any too).

Comment: Got it. Thx....

Comment: @Mick It is worth to add that $x,y$ may be negative (for example, if $a+c>S$ then $x<0$). In general, $-S\le x,y\le S$.

Comment: I guess we need not worry about the special cases that you have mentioned in your last comment because we are talking about the physical lengths such that cases like $a+c>S$ will not happen.

Comment: @Mick $a$ and $c$ are lengths on the opposite sides of the square, so $a+c>S$ is very physical. For example, if the point $Q\in BC$ will move to the left of the point $S\in AB$ we'll get negative $x$.

Answer (score 1):

If the vertices of the inner quadrilateral would be at $P,S,Y,X$ its area would be obviously half the area of the square. What happens if we move $X$ towards $Q$ and $Y$ towards $R$?

$$[PSYX]=[PSRQ]+[PXQ]+[RYQ]-[XQY]-[SRY].$$

Comment: Good to learn that $[PSYX] = \frac {1}{2}[ABCD]$ as a starting point.